# Helper class is not found in my java code

Tags: java, apache, openoffice-impress

I am trying to integrate Apache open office sdk for Power point ,So that i have to use helper class but it is not found in ellipse IDE and Java JDK 8 also.Why?

```
com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext xOfficeContext = Helper.connect();



        xDrawDoc = Helper.createDocument( xOfficeContext,
            "private:factory/simpress", "_blank", 0, pPropValues );




        // create pages, so that three are available
        while ( PageHelper.getDrawPageCount( xDrawDoc ) < 3 )
            PageHelper.insertNewDrawPageByIndex( xDrawDoc, 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache open office sdk is not a part of Java JDK. You have to download the jar file and add it to your project or use Maven.

[check this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openoffice/juh/3.2.1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use helper class in your java code You have to add **UNO** jar file.

use this link:

[check this link](http://%20check%20this%20link)